# Can TensorFlow Models be Updated on the fly for Android Apps

Tags: android, machine-learning, tensorflow

We have a requirement where models need to be updated on the flow . We could use some API to get the latest models . Is updating models possible when we use TensorFlow for android . If not are there any suggested alternatives ?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow models are represented by [`GraphDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d90f60a7a445c59fbc26ba47e53873ecb2022950/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.proto) protocol buffers (assuming you have [frozen](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/#freezing) the weights into the graph; otherwise, they typically require a separate checkpoint file). Therefore you could fetch an updated model via an RPC interface—such as [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/), which handles protocol buffers as standard—and use it to create a new TensorFlow session in your Android app.